# C - Strange behavior with fprintf

Tags: c, special-characters, printf

I have a project where the program saves some messages into a log file. At the start of my program, I open this file and functions write the text in it. As I'm brazilian, we have special caractares like ç, ã and others.

The problem I'm having is that in one of the files, I have the following line:

```
fprintf(logfile, "\nArquivo \"Instruções.txt\" criado\n");
```

and it works perfectly. The log file is correct.

Another file, of the same project has the following line:

```
fprintf(logfile, "Carregando configurações\n");
```

and the logfile is incorrect with 'Ã§Ãµ' instead of 'çõ'.

It's important to notice that I didn't close the file and reopened in the meantime, it's the same from beginning to the end and the second line I've shown is the first command to write in the file.

Another point is that if I copy that first line to the file of the second line, I get the same strange symbols, and the same problem if doing the opposite.

Now I don't have any idea what's going on. I've tried using %c and the number corresponding the characters (I use this method when using the console), but get the same problem.

Thanks very much!

EDIT: I don't know if it was clear, but at the same log file, there's both correct and incorrect letters. It's juts different files of the project that have the commands.

Comment: View the log file as UTF-8.

Comment: I'm doing that, the same problem

Comment: You're not. If this were UTF-8 decoding problems, you would see UNICODE replacement characters. Instead we're seeing what 2-byte UTF-8 shift sequences would look like if they were interpreted with another single-byte encoding.

Comment: I just used Notepad++ and CodeBlocks to open the file and both show the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the log file is being interpreted as some old encoding. Nowadays, most things are written in UNICODE. In this case, C does not care what format your string is, but since most things are UTF-8 these days, it's unlikely that you ended up with any other kind of string.

In this case, we can tell, because UTF-8 escape sequences look like this when not properly interpreted; When you improperly interpret something else as UTF-8, e.g. the other way around, you'll see UNICODE replacement characters instead.

If you are using Notepad and can't figure out a way to open the file with UTF-8, try another text editor. There's tons - gedit, Notepad++, etc.

Also: if you're wondering why it's all not gibberish, that's because UTF-8 is an ASCII-compatible encoding. The first 128 characters are assigned the same in UTF-8 as ASCII. A lot of character sets share this property, or at least are close to it.

Edit: Upon further questions, it does appear something fishy is going on. At the very least, though, it is definitely some weird encoding issue.

Comment: Opened with Notepad++ and got the same problem

Comment: After looking it up, it has become apparent that Notepad++ is actually not very good at UNICODE. In that case, I'm at a loss. You'll have to check preferences and try to force UTF-8.

Comment: I've selected UTF-8 encoding and no difference

Comment: Could be a problem with the .c file and something is corrupted but CodeBlocks shows it right to me? I've tried to copy and paste all the code to a new file and overwrite it, but no success.

Comment: Yes. It is possible that you're seeing two levels of indirection, i.e. UTF-8 interpreted as some other character set encoded as UTF-8. However, if that is the case, check your CodeBlocks settings. It should let you force UTF-8 always, which is generally what you want.

Comment: yeah, I found it, but nothing changes. I tought could be it because as one file of the project works and other doesn't, it could be the problem. Unless I have to rewrite all these symbols to fix it

Comment: But all the .c files I've opened with notepad (not notepad++) shows the content right. I have no idea

Comment: Yes, you have stumbled upon something very odd. If you want to, you can view files in a hex editor (i.e. HxD) to examine what exactly is going on. For your special characters, you should only be seeing 2-byte UTF-8 sequences - in both the .c files, and your log files. They'll look like 0xC0 0xFE (if I remember correctly.) The rest will be one byte.

Comment: I've managed to change all the files to UTF-8 at Code Blocks using Edit>File encoding. Now every special character is wrong at the log file. It means that the encoding that I was using befores was working and UTF-8 is not. Should I use UNICODE?

Comment: Edit > File encoding > System default makes everything works fine. But shouldn't UTF-8 work fine too? Could it be a compiler problem?

Comment: Not really sure what to say. I'm guessing CodeBlocks is in the wrong here, but things are not acting intuitively, that's for sure.

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the encoding method your editor uses to display your log files, configure your editor to use the UTF-8 encoding, should be fine.

Comment: but I don't understand why some of them works ok and some don't